# How can you force errors in TypeScript with noImplicitAny:false while using explicit Type Assertion in Bracket Notation?

Tags: typescript

So let's say you're working on a production code base that was done in typescript but is old and has a bunch of implicit `any` - stuff like `object[key]`. You may decide to turn the `noImplicitAny` flag off so you don't have a sea of compile errors.

But as you add new code to the project, you want some better safety when using bracket notation. I would think you should be able simply use Type Assertion to do this but what I'm seeing is it still implicitly infers literals as `any` (unless the string is close to the key, more on that below...). It seems like a bug to me but interested if anyone can explain what I'm doing wrong or not understanding here before I open an issue.

Say you have an object literal like:

```js
let someObj = {
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2"
};
```

And you try to access it like this:

```js
let value = someObj['not a valid key'];
```

If the noImplicitAny flag is off, then the string literal will implicitly be any and no checking on the key happens - with the flag on, you get exactly the errors you'd expect.

So you would think with the flag off you could still do this for new code to get safety:

```js
let value = someObj['not a valid key' as keyof typeof someObj];
```

But the above produces no errors, and to go even further, if I turn the flag back on, it will say, "value implicitly has any type, etc...". So why the heck would TypeScript still implicitly convert it to `any` when I've explicitly asserted what it's supposed to be?

If you use a variable, it works as expected, so why not with Type Assertion?

```js
let key: keyof typeof someObj = 'not valid key'; // Compile error just like you'd expect.
```

Another note - if you try Type Assertion with another type (non-string) it will cause an error like, `"Conversion of type 'number' to type '"key1" | "key2"' may be a mistake..."` - so it clearly knows what is supposed to be passed in but it does not seem to be honoring how (I think) `keyof T` is supposed to guard for invalid keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If the noImplicitAny flag is off, then the string literal will implicitly be any and no checking on the key happens

Given `noImplicitAny: true` and the assignment

```
let value = someObj['not a valid key'];
```

, TS looks for an explicit key or a suitable index signature of the type resulting from `value`. As the type has no property `'not a valid key'` and no declared index signature, the property value will implicitely become `any`, which violates `noImplicitAny`. Without this config option, implicit `any` will be OK.

> If you use a variable, it works as expected, so why not with Type Assertion?

Because the compiler checks are slightly different for [type assertions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#416-type-assertions) and [assignments](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3114-assignment-compatibility). For an assignment like

```
let key: keyof typeof someObj = 'not valid key'; // Compile error just like you'd expect.
```

, one type compatibility rule is (`S = 'not valid key'`, `T = 'key1'|'key2'` ):

> S is assignable to a type T [if] T is a union type and S is assignable to at least one constituent type of T.

`'not valid key'` isn't assignable to both `'key1'` or `'key2'`, so that doesn't compile. For [type assertions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20849#issuecomment-353480448), the rule is a bit [different](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#416-type-assertions):

> In a type assertion expression of the form < T > e, [...] the resulting type of e is required to be assignable to T, or T is required to be assignable to the [widened](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676) form of the resulting type of e, or otherwise a compile-time error occurs. The type of the result is T.
>
> Type assertions check for assignment compatibility in both directions. Thus, type assertions allow type conversions that might be correct, but aren't known to be correct.

Also for [type compatibility of unions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20849#issuecomment-353717944), it is sufficient, if any given constituent of a union is compatible to the other type (yup, sometimes those "gold nuggets" of information are spread deeply in github issues and not only in the core docs). So in the assignment (`T = 'key1'|'key2'`, `e = 'not a valid key'`)

```
let value = someObj['not a valid key' as keyof typeof someObj];
```

, `'key1'` or `'key2'` are both assignable to the widened ([`= string`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676)) form of `'not a valid key'` and we are good to go - no compile errors!

Hope, you are still awake and things got clarified a bit.

Comment: Ugh, I don't like it but thank you for clarifying and providing great resources. Any comment on why it will show an error for type assertion if you use a string that is very close to the key (i.e., 'ke' - TS will say, "did you mean 'key'?")? I found it inconsistent that it would show an error/warning there, but be okay with some totally off string. Also, do you know of any way to achieve this without a variable since type assertion is so loose?

Comment: Can you provide a playground that illustrates both of your questions, so I can have a look at a concrete example?

Comment: Aw dang, sorry I must have tripped myself at some point testing all this. The error with a suggestion for a close key is only when you have the noImplicitAny flag **on** - I must have thought it was off when I saw that, just updated my question to not include that - I think you answered everything and the "type compatibility of unions" link was the most insightful for anyone else reading - they clearly describe how loose type assertion is meant to be and the trade-offs. Thanks again.

Comment: No worries, glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

In this example, what 'as' does is it asserts that 'not a valid key' is really 'key1' | 'key2'. That's okay because you can assert a type to be a similar type, a subtype, or a supertype. Asserting a string to a number doesn't work because they're not related.

```
let value = someObj['not a valid key' as keyof typeof someObj];
```

`as` is for type assertions, you're forcing the typechecker to assume something, and it'll basically be the same as assignment if you assert a string to be another string.

Going back to the first thing...

```
let value = someObj['not a valid key'];
```

Imagine this scenario:

```
let obj = {
  key1: 'hi',
  key2: 'hello'
};
let key = 'key1';
let f = () => {
  key = 'key2';
};
f();
obj[key]; // type any
obj[<keyof typeof obj>key]; // this is a workaround
```

Here `key` is set programmatically, regardless of your noImpicitAny flag TypeScript won't be able to infer type, but the workaround tells TypeScript to trust you basically.

For the typechecker to know exactly what you're trying to do use dot notation, then keys can't be set programmatically. (I know understand your question was how to not have to do this)

```
let value = someObj.key3;
```

Now `someObj.key3` isn't any, its undefined and the typechecker will give an error regardless of the 'noImpicitAny' flag.

Comment: Thanks for the response but a couple problems with your answer: 1. I'm not asserting that it is a string, otherwise I'd totally agree. I'm asserting that it's keyof  typeof Obj wich I don't agree should allow implicit conversion to string - it should work as keyof T works everywhere else. Also this doesn't explain why when you make the string very close to a key, it's smart enough to error - that is very inconsistent IMO. 2. "someObj['not a valid key'] is of type any because typescript has no way of knowing what type that should be" - that's not right really, if noImplicitAny flag is on.

Comment: ...TS absolutely has a way to infer the type and will infer it as keyof typeof Obj if the flag is on - that's why I'm trying to explicitly assert the same - since I have the flag off. 3. The question is about Bracket Notation, dot notation is not a valid solution - say you need to access via string literal (because of invalid JS characters in the key for instance).

Comment: At the end of the day - keyof typeof Obj should not be able to be implicitly converted to `string` even, but worse it's being implicitly converted to `any`! That seems wrong IMO but you say that is fine why?

Comment: Hmm. Ok so for (1), 'keyof T' is equivalent to " 'key1' | 'key2' ", so its a super type of string. To see what I mean go into the editor, and try `let a = 'somestring' as keyof T`, it will do the conversion. For (2) Yes you're correct, I'm going to replace that demonstration to show what happens if you actually determine a key programmatically, try it and you'll see typescript fails to infer type even with noImplicitAny. And then its of type any and that's your issue. If you need to programmatically determine keys, then you'll get `any`s

Comment: I also discovered a workaround, let me know if that works for you. Honestly don't understand why that works and using `as` did the conversion.

Comment: That's interesting it works for you with angle bracket type assertion - that's normally what I do (and did at first) with same behavior that `as` shows. I'm not sure why that works for you, what TS version are you using if you don't mind?

Comment: And yes, we can agree on the behavior we're seeing - in OP I say it is converting strings that aren't close enough to a key to any, but if it is close it will error. I still disagree on what it **should** do - I think when you use `keyof T` it should be much stricter - I don't see why someone would type something as `keyof T` only to pass some other string to it, the intention is very clear. Also it really get's me with all the other errors like if you do a string that might be a typo it errors, but if it's totally off that's okay? Again, inconsistent IMO.