# Why do type assertions not validate as strongly as type declarations?

Tags: typescript

Given the following interface:

```
interface Request 
{
    name: string;
    email: string;
}
```

I would have thought that the following lines of code were functionally identical at design time:

```
var request1: Request = {name: "John"};
var request2 = {name: "John"} as Request;
```

But they are not. The second line compiles, whereas the first complains that the `email` property is missing.

If Typescript believes that all non-optional properties of the type must be specified, why doesn't it complain about type assertion using the `as Request` on an object that's missing a property.

And is there a casting syntax that would enforce this stronger typing? (The `<Request>(...)` syntax doesn't do so either.)

Comment: For a more in-depth answer, how type assertions work, you can look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58757997/5669456 . Note: The devs seem to have moved the TS specification document, if you encounter a dead link. It can be found under https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec-ARCHIVED.md.

Answer (score 6):

The purpose of a type assertion (either the `as Request` syntax of the `<Request>` syntax) is to tell typescript "i know better than you, so don't check my work here". For that reason, type checking is more or less turned off. It still does a very loose form of typechecking to rule out the more egregious cases, but that won't catch the case you have. (And if it does find something you can turn it completely off by doing `as unknown as Request`).

> And is there a casting syntax that would enforce this stronger typing?

If you want a strict type, then you use the colon syntax that you had on your first line.

```
var request1: Request = {name: "John"};
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I know this is a bit small, but I prefer the assertion syntax of `{...} as Type` to the assignment syntax, because it makes the type more prominent, being at the end of the line. Is there any way to write a cast-with-strong-checking syntax?

Comment: `Is there any way to write a cast-with-strong-checking syntax?` no, there is not.